# div position changes when zoom in /out

Tags: html, position, zooming

I had spent many hours in figuring out the solution to this problem and looking badly for help. Any pointers would be of great help.

I have an image positioned at the top right corner of the page. On click of this i have to show a drop down below the image.
Below is the code.

```
 <div style=\"margin-right: 3px;\"  >
           <div style=\"position:absolute;\">                        
          <a  href=\"javascript:testpopup()\" ><img id =\"Img\" align=\"left\"  src=\"qual.png\" onload=\"javascript:Count()\" /></a>" +

          <div id=\"Count\"    style=\"float: left;\"> </div>         
          </div>

           <div class=\"Popup_Position\" style=\"position:absolute;display:block;\" > 
               <div id=\"Table\" style=\"position:absolute;display:block;width: 278px;\"    >

                  </div>


            </div>
     </div>
```

The div Count is positioned next to the image and div Table is positioned below the image.
It works fine in 100% zoom. But when zoom in/out, the div moves away from the image. Also the content in the zoom overflows and the div size gets changed.
Please suggest what can be done.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this style with image:

```
 <a  href=\"javascript:testpopup()\" ><img id =\"Img\" align=\"left\"  src=\"qual.png\" onload=\"javascript:Count()\" style=\"max-width:100%;\" /></a>"
```

This must solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, Tried the solution but no luck. The div still moves away from the image when zoom in /out